# JSON in node.js

Tags: json, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON array in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911438/json-array-in-node-js)

Im kinda new to node.js and Im working on only the server side to answer POST from the client side. What i need to do is when a POST request is made at location '/sort' with parameter 'theArray', sort the array removing all non-string values and return the resulting value as JSON. theArray parameter will be a stringified JSON Array.
I have tried this code here:

```
case '/sort':
        if (req.method == 'POST') {
            res.writeHead(200,{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            });
            var fullArr = "";
                req.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    fullArr += chunk;
                    });
                req.on('end', function() {
                            var query = JSON.parse(fullArr);
                            var arr = "";
                            var par = query.theArray;
                            arr += par;
                    console.log(arr); 

                                function censor(key, value) {
                                    if (typeof value == "string") {
                                            return value;
                                        } 
                                        return undefined;
                                        }
                        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(arr, censor);
                        console.log(jsonString);
                });         
                    res.end();


        };
```

break;

But it just returns the same thing? I have also tried replacing the qs.parse with the JSON.parse and it just returned undefined? Can someone please help! Thanks

Comment: So the difference between using qs or JSON for parse depends on you, what do you send to this POST ? a Body urlencoded or a JSON string ?

Comment: I guess i should have been a little but more specific about this. But i dont have control over what is sent. this is kinda like an assignment. I think it is urlencoded though because when messing with some code ive gotten back an error and the console.log showed undefined and some code that looked to be encoded (%2b%3...). But either parse doesnt tack out the non-string values?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

1. Request data received by chunks. There is absolutely no guarantees that you receive all data in first chunk. You need to parse input data only after '[end](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_end)' event fired.
2. In censor function you have undefined variable 'i'. Do you mean 'key'?

Comment: thanks i have edited the code above. but i think that i would be looking for the value because the parameter given would be something like: {"theArray":"[[],\"d\",\"B\",{},\"b\",12,\"A\",\"c\"]"} But i still get the same results

Comment: God I am probably just over thinking this and after 4 days of trying every code that i come across I am probably confusing myself by now

Comment: If fullArr is {"theArray":"[[],\"d\",\"B\",{},\"b\",12,\"A\",\"c\"]"} qs.parse do not parse it. qs.parse designed for something like this: a=1&b=2&c=3. Try JSON.parse.

Comment: Okay well then if i just try and respond with the fullArr it responds it coded like this "theArray=%5B%5B%5D%2C%22d%22%..'

Comment: i have also tried the JSON.parse and it give a result of undefined:1 and then gives an error starting with the code result like this %2C%22A%22%2C%22 SyntaxError: Unexpected token h

Comment: ill update the code again to show what im running

Answer (score 0):

wait till the request has ended.. then parse your fullArray

```
var data = ""
req.on('data',function(chunk){data+=chunk})
req.on('end',function(){...parse here....})
```

Comment: thanks i edited the code above but still get the same results