# JSON array in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have been trying to figure this out for the past week and everything that i try just doesn't seem to work.

I have to create a web service on my local box that responds to requests. The client (that i did not write) will ask my service one question at a time, to which my server should respond with an appropriate answer.

So the last thing i have to do is:

- When a **POST** request is made at location **'/sort'** with parameter ***'theArray'***, sort the array **removing all non-string values** and return the resulting value as **JSON**.

  - ***theArray*** parameter will be a stringified JSON Array

From going through trail and error i have found out that the parameters supplied is:

```
{"theArray":"[[],\"d\",\"B\",{},\"b\",12,\"A\",\"c\"]"}
```

I have tried many different thing to try to get this to work. But the closest thing i can get is it only returning the same thing or nothing at all. This is the code that i am using to get those results:

```
case '/sort':
        if (req.method == 'POST') {
            res.writeHead(200,{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            });
            var fullArr = "";
                req.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    fullArr += chunk;
                    });
                req.on('end', function() {
                            var query = qs.parse(fullArr);
                            var strin = qs.stringify(query.theArray)
                            var jArr = JSON.parse(fullArr);
                    console.log(jArr); // Returns undefided:1 
                            var par = query.theArray;
                    console.log(par); // returns [[],"d","B",{},"b",12,"A","c"]

                                function censor(key) {
                                    if (typeof key == "string") {
                                            return key;
                                        } 
                                        return undefined;
                                        }
                        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(par, censor);
                   console.log(jsonString); // returns ""
                });         
                    res.end();


        };

break;
```

Just to clarify what I need it to return is `["d","B","b","A","c"]`

So if someone can please help me with this and if possible responded with some written code that is kinda set up in a way that would already work with the way i have my code set up that would be great! Thanks

Comment: So, your object is being correctly parsed and you just need to take the string elements? It is more a algorithm question. Am I correct?

Comment: i would say yeah kinda. I just need the sting from the array to be returned. So the [], {} , and 12 need to be taken out so i can just return the strings

Comment: Ok. Take a look in my answer. I will try to do the way you are trying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** Try this:

```
var query = {"theArray":"[[],\"d\",\"B\",{},\"b\",12,\"A\",\"c\"]"};
var par = JSON.parse(query.theArray);
var stringArray = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < par.length; i++ ) {
    if ( typeof par[i] == "string" ) {
        stringArray.push(par[i]);
    }
}
var jsonString = JSON.stringify( stringArray );
console.log(jsonString);
```

P.S. I didnt't pay attention. Your array was actually a string. Andrey, thanks for the tip.

Comment: it looks par is json as string in his example

Comment: try `console.log(typeof(par))`

Comment: Parse the string that represents an array first.

Comment: console.log(typeof(par)) return string

Comment: try to start your example with `var formdata = 'theArray"%3A"%5B%5B%5D%2C%5C"d%5C"%2C%5C"B%5C"%2C%7B%7D%2C%5C"b%5C"%2C12%2C%5C"A%5C"%2C%5C"c%5C"%5D"'` :)

Answer (score 0):

edit: one-liner (try it in repl!)

```
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(require('querystring').parse('theArray=%5B%5B%5D%2C"d"%2C"B"%2C%7B%7D%2C"b"%2C12%2C"A"%2C"c"%5D').theArray).filter(function(el) {return typeof(el) == 'string'}));
```

code to paste to your server:

```
case '/sort':
        if (req.method == 'POST') {
            buff = '';
            req.on('data', function(chunk) { buff += chunk.toString() });
            res.on('end', function() {
              var inputJsonAsString = qs.parse(fullArr).theArray;
              // fullArr is x-www-form-urlencoded string and NOT a valid json (thus undefined returned from JSON.parse)
              var inputJson = JSON.parse(inputJsonAsString);
              var stringsArr = inputJson.filter(function(el) {return typeof(el) == 'string'});
              res.writeHead(200,{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
              });
              res.end(JSON.stringify(stringsArr));
        };
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `replacer` parameter of `JSON.stringify` doesn't work quite like you're using it; check out [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter).

You could use `Array.prototype.filter` to filter out the elements you don't want:

```
var arr = [[],"d","B",{},"b",12,"A","c"];
arr = arr.filter(function(v) { return typeof v == 'string'; });
arr // => ["d", "B", "b", "A", "c"]
```